# How to run a Maven project containing junit test class in windows command line?

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, junit

[image: Warnings During Build]I am new to MAVEN and Junit .I am trying to run a maven project that has junit test and cucumber Feature files in command line.
It shows "Build Success" but it also shows "nothing to Compile". Its a web automation code using Selenium with cucumber feature file.Could somebody please help me to Run this in command line of windows.Here is the POM file.(Project is not having Main class.)

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>BFL</groupId>
  <artifactId>Web_Automation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Web_Automation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.35.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
     <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.14.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>test_runner.WEBRUNNER</mainClass>        
            <systemPropertyVariables>
             <!-- <retryCount>${retryCount}</retryCount> -->
              <!-- <accountBrowser>${myaccountBrowser}</accountBrowser>
              <searchBrowser>${searchBrowser}</searchBrowser>
              <pdpBrowser>${pdpBrowser}</pdpBrowser>
              <browseBrowser>${browseBrowser}</browseBrowser>
              <cartBrowser>${cartBrowser}</cartBrowser>
              <globalNavBrowser>${globalNavBrowser}</globalNavBrowser>
              <homeBrowser>${homeBrowser}</homeBrowser>-->
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just ran the command of "mvn test" after locating the project directory that contains POM file and other code packages.

Comment: And you should have a number of WARNING during the build ....

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for replying.Yeah..I got an Warning "The artifact org.apache.commons:common-io:jar :1.3.2 has been relocated to common-io:commons-io:jar:13.2"

Comment: That means you are using the wrong dependency. First this needs to be fixed. Apart from using JUnit 3 ...I have my doubts if this is correct....

Comment: ok...But my doubt is if its a wrong dependency..it should not work in eclipse right?

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, I also got some more warnings which i have noted now...I posted as a pic in my question .Could you please Take a look?

Comment: As mentioned in the output ...clean up your dependencies cause you have defined some of them as duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest remove plugin of `maven-surefire-plugin` and add scope as `test` in `junit` and `cucumber-junit` dependency as mentioned below

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>  
    <scope>test</scope>      
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>        
</dependency>
```

Now locate root directory of project in command line and try below command to run

```
mvn test
```

Comment: There is no dependency to `maven-surefire-plugin` it's defined in pluginManagement which is something different than a dependency.

Comment: My mistake. I meant plugin.